# Local storage in react isn't keeping state on a refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to keep state on a refresh in my React application using this code:

```
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(localStorage.getItem('darkMode') || false);
  const [mode, setMode] = useState({bg: 'light', variant: 'light'})

  const toggleDarkMode = () => {
    if (darkMode === true) {
      setMode({bg: 'light', variant: 'light'})
      setDarkMode(false);
      localStorage.setItem("darkMode", false );
    } else {
      setMode({bg: 'dark', variant: 'dark'})
      setDarkMode(true);
      localStorage.setItem("darkMode", true );
    }
  };
```

`toggleDarkMode` is called by a button `onChange` event.

But when I refresh or go to a different URL the state is lost. It's important to keep this state as its for the dark / light mode.

I have tried calling local storage using `window.localStorage` and tried to place it in `useEffect` so it would update constantly but the state still seems to be lost. I've also tried parsing it as JSON which a lot of tutorials recommend but that also doesn't seem to work.

Occasionly on a new page instance I'll get the error about bg cannot be undefined, which makes me think the state isn't being stored.

Why is the state being lost and is there a better / more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Local storage stores a string, so `darkMode` will be `"true"` not `true` when loaded directly from storage unless you parse it.

Comment: Local storage will only store strings

Comment: Thank you. Theoretically would the code work if bools were allowed?

Comment: You can use `JSON.parse()` for the result from `getItem` and `JSON.stringify` to pass your variables to `setItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local Storage can only store Strings. By updating `toggleDarkMode` to check against string values x or y I can solve the problem.

```
  const [bool, setBool] = useState(localStorage.getItem('bool') || 'False')
  const [mode, setMode] = useState((bool === 'False') ? {bg: 'light', variant: 'light'} : {bg: 'dark', variant: 'dark'})

  const toggleDarkMode = () => {
    if (bool === 'True') {
      setMode({bg: 'light', variant: 'light'})
      setBool('False')
      localStorage.setItem("bool", 'False' );
    } else {
      setMode({bg: 'dark', variant: 'dark'})
      setBool('True')
      localStorage.setItem("bool", 'True' );
    }
  };
```

Credit to [DBS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1650337/dbs) and [assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8036670/assembler)

Answer (score -1):

dark mode value upbate using **contexApi** or **redux**. Its have two benefits

1. not need local  state **setDarkMode**
2. When the update dark mode it provides an updated value.

use this **??** instead of **||** optare.

````
```  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(localStorage.getItem('darkMode')?? false);
````

Comment: I have solved it by changing the bools to strings and checking against the strings instead. Thank you though!